# How to Create a Joomla!-based Online Course

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, user, joomla-3.5

I'm creating a website on the Joomla! 3.5 platform (This is so I can tie in directly to another Joomla! site user database.) that is a simple 5-section training course used to train a company's internal sales reps--probably 8 pages total. The issue is that I need to verify each video within the 5 sections has been watched and a certain number of questions at the end of each section has been completed. Upon completion of the test with 80% correct answers, a certificate will be mailed to the user's address given.

I've found several LMS (Learning Management System) solutions online including:

- [Joomla LMS](https://www.joomlalms.com/)
- [Course Manager](http://joomla.profinvent.com/index.php?option=com_profishop&view=products&id=2&categoryid=2&Itemid=103)
- [Guru](https://guru.ijoomla.com/)
- [OSG Seminar Manager](http://sman.osg-gmbh.de/en)
- [LMS King](https://www.king-products.net/kingproducts)

However, all of these seem overly complicated for a single FREE course which is fully protected by login. Is there an LMS solution that would work, or should I be looking in a different direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked on a rather similar project, where there is a training program for subscribed users, controlling the access with a memberships component. The learning material is organized using Zoo CCK, containing both text and a video tutorial for each lesson.

We have next, previous buttons at the bottom of each lesson page, and at the end of each learning section, we have a quiz to test/verify user's learning /progress.

For the quizzes we are using a component called **[Joomla Quiz Deluxe by Joomplace](https://www.joomplace.com/elearning-extensions/joomla-quiz-deluxe.html)**, which is quiet flexible. It allows creation of unlimited custom quizzes, with a passing score and it can also print a certificate of success.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like we posted the same solution minutes apart! :)

Comment: I've marked yours as the answer in order to share the love! However, I'll just be using the J! Articles manager for the content in order to reduce overhead of the site (only 8 pages). Otherwise, I would prefer K2. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: What method did you use for next /previous buttons? Manually adding them at the bottom of each article? Multiple page breaks in the articles? How do you keep users from skipping lessons and just going straight to the quiz?

Answer (score 2):

After further searching, I have found that the [Joomla! Quiz Deluxe Component](https://www.joomplace.com/elearning-extensions/joomla-quiz-deluxe.html) will meet all of my needs, and even generates a certificate of completion automatically!